# How to save NSUserDefaults upon applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have an NSUserDefaults style score structure in my game, and wish to save these values upon terminating the app. Is there some kind of methods which save and re-load from file upon reopening?

Comment: There are two things you need to understand to get this working: the lifecycle of an iOS app and which app delegate methods are called within this lifecycle.  How to save/load `NSUserDefault` values.  Both are well documented on here and all over the internet, so please search before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Save them after each change (or, if you know you will have lots of changes in a short space of time, batch save them after the updates).

`applicationWillTerminate:` is basically never called in the current version of iOS (since backgrounding was introduced) so you shouldn't rely on it. Also, consider what would happen if your app crashed and none of the user information had been saved - not a good user experience.

So, don't rely on `applicationWillTerminate:`, ever, for anything...

Answer (score 0):

After setting the`NSUserDefaults` values in `applicationWillTerminate`, ensure you call `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize]` so that the changes are immediately flushed to disk and persisted between app launches.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10.3.2 , even if we call synchronize, the data is not persisted to disk. This is a problem only when we are trying to set value and synchronize data in "applicationWillTerminate". This could be a bug.

So If want to save some information when application terminates you can write it to a plist file and store it in document directory. I have tested and it works.

**Swift 3.0.2**:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let plistPath = getPath()

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: plistPath) {

        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: plistPath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)

    }

    let data:NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    data.setValue("test_Value", forKey: "test_key")
    data.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)
}


func getPath() -> String {
    let plistFileName = "data.plist"
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentPath = paths[0] as NSString
    let plistPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(plistFileName)
    return plistPath
}

func displaySavedData() {
    let plistPath = self.getPath()
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: plistPath) {
        if let savedData = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath) {
            print(savedData)
        }
    }
}
```

When application is launched, values can be accessed as below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    displaySavedData()
    return true

}
```

As described in other answers, "applicationWillTerminate" will not get called incase the app supports background mode, so this solution is useful when your app does not support background mode and you know that killing the application is calling "applicationWillTerminate".